# Java Hadoop: open folder in HDFS in order to read

Tags: java, dictionary, hadoop, reduce

I'm trying to read a post-proccesed file for reduce step in it's setup() method  using:

```
FSDataInputStream singlesInputStream = fs.open(new Path("/output/1/part-r-00000")); //singles
```

The file contains entries for a large map with key and values.

With low-sized inputs in was fine, but for a larger input hadoop splits the output file according to the reducers count.
So I tried using:

```
FSDataInputStream singlesInputStream = fs.open(new Path("/output/1/")); //note the path
```

which does not work and throws an exception:

```
Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Path is not a file: /output/1
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:75)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:61)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1828)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1799)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1712)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:588)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)
```

1. Is there an option to load a hdfs folder and stream it? I can't find the correct api.
2. I want to load the data into a large map (about 0.5 million entries) for all reducers in this map/reduce step. Is there a better way to load it and share the map between reducers, I'm pretty sure Hadoop has framework support for that.

Comment: Mapreduce framework can already read a folder... Can you show the rest of the code? How about `"/output/1/*"`?

Comment: I've managed to list the files in the folder, get their path and read all of them one by one, while filling the map with the data.
From what I've seen, input data as folder works only for map/reduce jobs, not for reading files during setup process for the reduce class.